# HttpWebRequest to SLL Uri in Silverlight 2.0

Tags: ssl, https, httpwebrequest, silverlight-2.0

How do I do this? It seems the SilverLight 2.0 HttpWebRequest does not allow you to set Credentials or set the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search on this turned up this link, which seems to have a workaround.

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/48143/127888.aspx